# Wrong width and height when using inset_axes and transData

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to plot an inset by specifying the width and height in the Data reference frame. However when converting these values to inches (as required by `inset_axes`) using `transData.transform` the inset axe doesn't respect the given width and height. Any idea why? Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes
from matplotlib.projections import get_projection_class,get_projection_names

fig,ax_main=plt.subplots()
width=0.5
height=0.5
x_center=0
y_center=0

new_width,_=(ax_main.transData.transform([width,0])-ax_main.transData.transform([0,0]))/72
_,new_height=(ax_main.transData.transform([0,height])-ax_main.transData.transform([0,0]))/72
print(new_width,new_height)

### Process
ax_val= inset_axes(ax_main, width=new_width, height=new_height, loc=3, 
                   bbox_to_anchor=(x_center,y_center),
                   bbox_transform=ax_main.transData, 
                   borderpad=0.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I don't know in how far the result is unexpected, the problem might be due to the wrong conversion used. `transData` transforms from data in pixel space. You divide the result by 72. The result of this may or may not be inches, depending on whether the figure dpi is 72 or not. By default the dpi is set to value from the rc params `"figure.dpi"` and that is 100 for a fresh matplotlib install and in case you haven't changed your rc params.

To be on the safe side,

- either set your figure dpi to 72, `plt.subplots(dpi=72)`
- or divide by the figure dpi, `(ax_main.... ) / fig.dpi`

However, much more generally, it seems you want to set the width and height of the `inset_axes` in data coordinates. So best don't specify the size in inches at all. Rather use the bounding box directly.

```
ax_val = inset_axes(ax_main, width="100%", height="100%", loc=3, 
                    bbox_to_anchor=(x_center,y_center,width,height),
                    bbox_transform=ax_main.transData, 
                    borderpad=0.0)
```

I updated the [`inset_axes` documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.0.0/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator.inset_axes.html) as well as the [example](https://matplotlib.org/3.0.0/gallery/axes_grid1/inset_locator_demo.html) a couple of months ago, so hopefully this case should also be well covered. However feel free to give feedback in case some information is still missing.

Even more interesting here might be the new option in matplotlib 3.0, to not use the `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator`, but the [`Axes.inset_axes`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.inset_axes.html) method. It's still noted to be "experimental" but should work fine.

```
ax_val = ax_main.inset_axes((x_center,y_center,width,height), transform=ax_main.transData)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot (again) ! Works like a charm! I mistakenly thought that 72 dpi was a standard.

Comment: However I just realized that the solution mentioned above with (width,height ) inside `bbox_to_anchor` doesn't work for polar projections, it seems that in the case of polar projections the `loc` parameter is omitted

Comment: When using the 4 tuple and a width/height of 100% what exactly is the `loc` parameter supposed to do?

Comment: I suppose that when choosing `loc=10` the polar plot should be centered on the given `x_center,y_center`. For the moment there is no difference between `loc=3` and `loc=10` for example.

Comment: That should not depend on the polar plot at all. For normal plots you should observe the same. The point is, if an element fills up the complete space ("100%") of a rectangle, it doesn't matter where inside this rectangle you anchor ("loc") it. This is what I tried to convey with the blue dotted rectangle in the second plot in [the example](https://matplotlib.org/3.0.0/gallery/axes_grid1/inset_locator_demo.html).